# Are there any plans to create a UX Designer survey like the StackOverflow Developer survey?

Tags: feature-request

I have been looking at the StackOverflow Developer survey results for years and hoping that something like that is in the pipeworks for UXSE as well. With such a large community and active users, it would seem like a logical idea to represent both the designers and developers of the IT industry to provide a more complete picture.

Does anyone know anything about when this might happen, or if it is even planned?